# How to use Spring Hatoas ControllerLinkBuilder for a Thymeleaf templated scheduled email

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring Hateoas in a Boot app to avoid manual creation of links in the view. It works great in Thymeleaf views, it works when a controller calls a service to send an email that is also rendered by Thymeleaf.

The code to create link is pretty standard

```
this.readLink = linkTo(methodOn(PostController.class)
    .readPost(eventId, postId))
    .withRel("ReadPost");
```

But for a `@Scheduled` service generated email, it fails like this

```
015-08-23 22:28:40.886 ERROR 1180 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder. Is this being called from a Spring MVC handler?
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392) ~[spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.getCurrentRequest(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:242) ~[spring-hateoas-0.18.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.getBuilder(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:189) ~[spring-hateoas-0.18.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.java:121) ~[spring-hateoas-0.18.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Is there anything I can do to get around the lack of an `HttpServletRequest` due to the code running as a `@Scheduled` job?

Comment: This is a major outstanding problem that I'm trying to bring up with the Spring Data team this week. Right now there's no practical workaround.

Comment: Ok thanks, not just me then, that's something

Comment: Did you get anything from the Spring Data Team on this?

Comment: Basically, don't hold your breath.

Comment: Bump, similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

`ControllerLinkBuilder` currently can only be used from within a request as only that allows it to create a fully qualified link using server and port information from it.

Within an `@Scheduled`-invoked method that information is not available. If you provide more information on what you're actually creating in that very method, I can suggest workarounds.

Comment: I'm trying to use Thymeleaf to generate a HTML email with a list of links to new posts. What I wanted to do was use Hateoas to generate the links, add them to the Context and pass that to the TemplatingEngine. I've had to change the code now to work around this problem but it's not as pretty as the Hateoas solution would have been because the endpoint is now hardcoded in the html template. The Hateoas way it was only hardcoded in the controller, which I liked a lot.